# bootstrap-select - dropdown disappeares when i add selectpicker class to the select tag

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

When i add the `selectpicker` class to my select tag and run my page in the browser, it doesn't show any `<select>` box...
Detail, when i remove the `selectpicker` class, it run normally. Anyway, it's possible to see the select box in code source.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.3/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>



<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>

<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="cidade">

<option value="test1">Test 1</option>
<option value="test2">Test 2</option>
<option value="test3">Test 3</option>
</select>

</body>
```

Comment: Add jQuery as Well

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. Through an `AJAX` request to my controller a string with the `HTML` was returned but I was not able to append it to the `DOM`. Nevertheless it appeared in the `DOM` upon inspection. It turned out that the problem was the `selectpicker` class. When removed, the `HTML` was appended successfully, and the element was *not* acting as expected, naturally.
After some search I came across the following solution:

`$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh')`

Found it [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_ajax/issues/2754763) with explanation why this might happen.
Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Place your JQuery script **before** your Bootstrap script.
It fixed it for me.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js" integrity="sha512-FHZVRMUW9FsXobt+ONiix6Z0tIkxvQfxtCSirkKc5Sb4TKHmqq1dZa8DphF0XqKb3ldLu/wgMa8mT6uXiLlRlw=="crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use bootstrap 3.3.7, you have to include JQuery befor the bootstrap plugin.
Like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- other javascript inludes follows -->
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution for disappering of the select when class=selectpicker. My problem occured when I added bootstrap select dynamically. After one day search I found my solution. I didn't saw this solution on the web.

The .selectpicker command must be used after appending the select item.. Here is my code below.

I hope this solution works for everyone..

```
var selectLocaleList = document.createElement("select");
selectLocaleList.setAttribute("id", "myLocaleSelect");
selectLocaleList.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
selectLocaleList.setAttribute("data-style", "btn-danger");
//Create and append the options
$(selectLocaleList).append('<option value="tr">Turkish</option>');
$(selectLocaleList).append('<option value="en">English</option>');
//This is the append code below that adds the select to the page. And this code must be ovet the .selectpicker 
modalBody.appendChild(selectLocaleList);
//And this is the .selectpicker after the append..
$(selectLocaleList).selectpicker('val', settings.locale)
                   .on('change', function () {
                       // Some functions
                   });
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to include jQuery *before* Bootstrap and bootstrap-select. In addition, you need to include all bootstrap-select files *after* all Bootstrap files (in your code, you're including bootstrap-select CSS before Bootstrap CSS).

Answer (score -1):

if you are populating the `<option>` dynamically, my suggestion is to refresh the `.selectpicker` after you finish append part
`$(".selectpicker").selectpicker('refresh');`